# How do I get co-ordinates of all gas/fuel/petrol stations on Google Maps?

Tags: android, firebase, google-places-api, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm developing a petrol price comparison app for my final year project in university (something similar to GasBuddy or PetrolPrices if you're living in the UK/US). I want to create an Android app that features an in-app map that's prepopulated with all the petrol stations in the country (Ireland).

I was going to use the Google Maps API for the in-app map and then add custom markers for all the petrol stations. I'm going to use Firebase as my database and wanted a section of it to be a list of all the petrol stations with their information such as; co-ordinates, opening times, petrol prices etc. I would use the Google Places API but I only want petrol stations to come up on the app without a user having to input a search query for them, which means the map will have to be pre-populated already.

Is there anyway that I can get all the co-ordinates of all the petrol stations listed on Google Maps to input into my database so I can prepopulate the in-app map with custom markers?

Comment: Sure it is, but have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Places API - Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) to achieve this. And by using the `type` filter and setting it to `gas_station`, you will get details of the place such as their coordinates. See this for the [list of supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types).

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

Be careful on what you store in your database. According to Google Maps [Terms of service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms) under 3.2.3 (a) No Scraping, customer will not: (i) pre-fetch, index, store, reshare, or rehost Google Maps Content outside the services

There is, however, some data that you can store/cache temporarily. See their [service specific terms](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms) for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep address types as `enum class` as follows. All `fields` are listed below.

```
enum class AddressType(private val addressType: String) {
    /** A precise street address.  */
    STREET_ADDRESS("street_address"),

    /** A precise street number.  */
    STREET_NUMBER("street_number"),

    /** The floor in the address of the building.  */
    FLOOR("floor"),

    /** The room in the address of the building  */
    ROOM("room"),

    /** A specific mailbox.  */
    POST_BOX("post_box"),

    /** A named route (such as "US 101").  */
    ROUTE("route"),

    /** A major intersection, usually of two major roads.  */
    INTERSECTION("intersection"),

    /** A continent.  */
    CONTINENT("continent"),

    /** A political entity. Usually, this type indicates a polygon of some civil administration.  */
    POLITICAL("political"),

    /** The national political entity, typically the highest order type returned by the Geocoder.  */
    COUNTRY("country"),

    /**
     * A first-order civil entity below the country level. Within the United States, these
     * administrative levels are states. Not all nations exhibit these administrative levels.
     */
    ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_1("administrative_area_level_1"),

    /**
     * A second-order civil entity below the country level. Within the United States, these
     * administrative levels are counties. Not all nations exhibit these administrative levels.
     */
    ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_2("administrative_area_level_2"),

    /**
     * A third-order civil entity below the country level. This type indicates a minor civil division.
     * Not all nations exhibit these administrative levels.
     */
    ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_3("administrative_area_level_3"),

    /**
     * A fourth-order civil entity below the country level. This type indicates a minor civil
     * division. Not all nations exhibit these administrative levels.
     */
    ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_4("administrative_area_level_4"),

    /**
     * A fifth-order civil entity below the country level. This type indicates a minor civil division.
     * Not all nations exhibit these administrative levels.
     */
    ADMINISTRATIVE_AREA_LEVEL_5("administrative_area_level_5"),

    /** A commonly-used alternative name for the entity.  */
    COLLOQUIAL_AREA("colloquial_area"),

    /** An incorporated city or town political entity.  */
    LOCALITY("locality"),

    /**
     * A specific type of Japanese locality, used to facilitate distinction between multiple locality
     * components within a Japanese address.
     */
    WARD("ward"),

    /**
     * A first-order civil entity below a locality. Some locations may receive one of the additional
     * types: `SUBLOCALITY_LEVEL_1` to `SUBLOCALITY_LEVEL_5`. Each sublocality level is a
     * civil entity. Larger numbers indicate a smaller geographic area.
     */
    SUBLOCALITY("sublocality"), SUBLOCALITY_LEVEL_1("sublocality_level_1"), SUBLOCALITY_LEVEL_2("sublocality_level_2"), SUBLOCALITY_LEVEL_3("sublocality_level_3"), SUBLOCALITY_LEVEL_4("sublocality_level_4"), SUBLOCALITY_LEVEL_5("sublocality_level_5"),

    /** A named neighborhood.  */
    NEIGHBORHOOD("neighborhood"),

    /** A named location, usually a building or collection of buildings with a common name.  */
    PREMISE("premise"),

    /**
     * A first-order entity below a named location, usually a singular building within a collection of
     * buildings with a common name.
     */
    SUBPREMISE("subpremise"),

    /** A postal code as used to address postal mail within the country.  */
    POSTAL_CODE("postal_code"),

    /** A postal code prefix as used to address postal mail within the country.  */
    POSTAL_CODE_PREFIX("postal_code_prefix"),

    /** A postal code prefix as used to address postal mail within the country.  */
    POSTAL_CODE_SUFFIX("postal_code_suffix"),

    /** A prominent natural feature.  */
    NATURAL_FEATURE("natural_feature"),

    /** An airport.  */
    AIRPORT("airport"),

    /** A university.  */
    UNIVERSITY("university"),

    /** A named park.  */
    PARK("park"),

    /** A museum.  */
    MUSEUM("museum"),

    /**
     * A named point of interest. Typically, these "POI"s are prominent local entities that don't
     * easily fit in another category, such as "Empire State Building" or "Statue of Liberty."
     */
    POINT_OF_INTEREST("point_of_interest"),

    /** A place that has not yet been categorized.  */
    ESTABLISHMENT("establishment"),

    /** The location of a bus stop.  */
    BUS_STATION("bus_station"),

    /** The location of a train station.  */
    TRAIN_STATION("train_station"),

    /** The location of a subway station.  */
    SUBWAY_STATION("subway_station"),

    /** The location of a transit station.  */
    TRANSIT_STATION("transit_station"),

    /** The location of a light rail station.  */
    LIGHT_RAIL_STATION("light_rail_station"),

    /** The location of a church.  */
    CHURCH("church"),

    /** The location of a primary school.  */
    PRIMARY_SCHOOL("primary_school"),

    /** The location of a secondary school.  */
    SECONDARY_SCHOOL("secondary_school"),

    /** The location of a finance institute.  */
    FINANCE("finance"),

    /** The location of a post office.  */
    POST_OFFICE("post_office"),

    /** The location of a place of worship.  */
    PLACE_OF_WORSHIP("place_of_worship"),

    /**
     * A grouping of geographic areas, such as locality and sublocality, used for mailing addresses in
     * some countries.
     */
    POSTAL_TOWN("postal_town"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    SYNAGOGUE("synagogue"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    FOOD("food"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    GROCERY_OR_SUPERMARKET("grocery_or_supermarket"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    STORE("store"),

    /** The location of a drugstore.  */
    DRUGSTORE("drugstore"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    LAWYER("lawyer"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    HEALTH("health"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    INSURANCE_AGENCY("insurance_agency"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    GAS_STATION("gas_station"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    CAR_DEALER("car_dealer"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    CAR_REPAIR("car_repair"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    MEAL_TAKEAWAY("meal_takeaway"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    FURNITURE_STORE("furniture_store"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    HOME_GOODS_STORE("home_goods_store"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    SHOPPING_MALL("shopping_mall"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    GYM("gym"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    ACCOUNTING("accounting"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    MOVING_COMPANY("moving_company"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    LODGING("lodging"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    STORAGE("storage"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    CASINO("casino"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    PARKING("parking"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    STADIUM("stadium"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    TRAVEL_AGENCY("travel_agency"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    NIGHT_CLUB("night_club"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    BEAUTY_SALON("beauty_salon"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    HAIR_CARE("hair_care"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    SPA("spa"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    SHOE_STORE("shoe_store"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    BAKERY("bakery"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    PHARMACY("pharmacy"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    SCHOOL("school"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    BOOK_STORE("book_store"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    DEPARTMENT_STORE("department_store"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    RESTAURANT("restaurant"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    REAL_ESTATE_AGENCY("real_estate_agency"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    BAR("bar"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    DOCTOR("doctor"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    HOSPITAL("hospital"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    FIRE_STATION("fire_station"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    SUPERMARKET("supermarket"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    CITY_HALL("city_hall"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    LOCAL_GOVERNMENT_OFFICE("local_government_office"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    ATM("atm"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    BANK("bank"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    LIBRARY("library"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    CAR_WASH("car_wash"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    HARDWARE_STORE("hardware_store"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    AMUSEMENT_PARK("amusement_park"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    AQUARIUM("aquarium"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    ART_GALLERY("art_gallery"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    BICYCLE_STORE("bicycle_store"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    BOWLING_ALLEY("bowling_alley"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    CAFE("cafe"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    CAMPGROUND("campground"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    CAR_RENTAL("car_rental"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    CEMETERY("cemetery"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    CLOTHING_STORE("clothing_store"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    CONVENIENCE_STORE("convenience_store"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    COURTHOUSE("courthouse"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    DENTIST("dentist"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    ELECTRICIAN("electrician"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    ELECTRONICS_STORE("electronics_store"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    EMBASSY("embassy"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    FLORIST("florist"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    FUNERAL_HOME("funeral_home"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    GENERAL_CONTRACTOR("general_contractor"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    HINDU_TEMPLE("hindu_temple"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    JEWELRY_STORE("jewelry_store"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    LAUNDRY("laundry"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    LIQUOR_STORE("liquor_store"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    LOCKSMITH("locksmith"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    MEAL_DELIVERY("meal_delivery"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    MOSQUE("mosque"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    MOVIE_RENTAL("movie_rental"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    MOVIE_THEATER("movie_theater"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    PAINTER("painter"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    PET_STORE("pet_store"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    PHYSIOTHERAPIST("physiotherapist"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    PLUMBER("plumber"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    POLICE("police"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    ROOFING_CONTRACTOR("roofing_contractor"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    RV_PARK("rv_park"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    TAXI_STAND("taxi_stand"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    VETERINARY_CARE("veterinary_care"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    ZOO("zoo"),

    /** An archipelago.  */
    ARCHIPELAGO("archipelago"),

    /** A tourist attraction  */
    TOURIST_ATTRACTION("tourist_attraction"),

    /** Currently not a documented return type.  */
    TOWN_SQUARE("town_square"),

    /**
     * Indicates an unknown address type returned by the server. The Java Client for Google Maps
     * Services should be updated to support the new value.
     */
    UNKNOWN("unknown");

    override fun toString(): String {
        return addressType
    }

}
```

**Your Activity or Fragment**

```
class ProgrammaticAutocompleteGeocodingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private val adapter = PlacePredictionAdapter()
    private val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(LatLng::class.java, LatLngAdapter()).create()

    private lateinit var queue: RequestQueue
    private lateinit var placesClient: PlacesClient
    private var sessionToken: AutocompleteSessionToken? = null

    private lateinit var viewAnimator: ViewAnimator
    private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_programmatic_autocomplete)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

        // Initialize members
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar)
        viewAnimator = findViewById(R.id.view_animator)
        placesClient = Places.createClient(this)
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        initRecyclerView()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
        val searchView = menu.findItem(R.id.search).actionView as SearchView
        initSearchView(searchView)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.search) {
            sessionToken = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance()
            return false
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    private fun initSearchView(searchView: SearchView) {
        searchView.queryHint = getString(R.string.search_a_place)
        searchView.isIconifiedByDefault = false
        searchView.isFocusable = true
        searchView.isIconified = false
        searchView.requestFocusFromTouch()
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                progressBar.isIndeterminate = true

                // Cancel any previous place prediction requests
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)

                // Start a new place prediction request in 300 ms
                handler.postDelayed({ getPlacePredictions(newText) }, 300)
                return true
            }
        })
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, layoutManager.orientation))
        // Get just the location of the place using the Geocoding API
        adapter.onPlaceClickListener = { geocodePlaceAndDisplay(it) }
        // Alternative: Get more details about the place using Place Details
        // See https://goo.gle/paaln for help choosing between Geocoding and Place Details
        // adapter.onPlaceClickListener = { fetchPlaceAndDisplay(it) }
    }

    /**
     * This method demonstrates the programmatic approach to getting place predictions. The
     * parameters in this request are currently biased to Kolkata, India.
     *
     * @param query the plus code query string (e.g. "GCG2+3M K")
     */
    private fun getPlacePredictions(query: String) {
        // The value of 'bias' biases prediction results to the rectangular region provided
        // (currently Kolkata). Modify these values to get results for another area. Make sure to
        // pass in the appropriate value/s for .setCountries() in the
        // FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.Builder object as well.
        val bias: LocationBias = RectangularBounds.newInstance(
            LatLng(22.458744, 88.208162),  // SW lat, lng
            LatLng(22.730671, 88.524896) // NE lat, lng
        )

        // Create a new programmatic Place Autocomplete request in Places SDK for Android
        val newRequest = FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest.builder()
            .setLocationBias(bias)
            .setCountries("IN")
            .setTypesFilter(listOf(PlaceTypes.ESTABLISHMENT))
            // Session Token only used to link related Place Details call. See https://goo.gle/paaln
            .setSessionToken(sessionToken)
            .setQuery(query)
            .build()

        // Perform autocomplete predictions request
        placesClient.findAutocompletePredictions(newRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener { response ->
                val predictions = response.autocompletePredictions
                adapter.setPredictions(predictions)
                progressBar.isIndeterminate = false
                viewAnimator.displayedChild = if (predictions.isEmpty()) 0 else 1
            }.addOnFailureListener { exception: Exception? ->
                progressBar.isIndeterminate = false
                if (exception is ApiException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: ${exception.message}")
                }
            }
    }

    /**
     * Performs a Geocoding API request and displays the result in a dialog.
     * Be sure to enable Geocoding API in your project and API key restrictions.
     *
     * @see https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically
     */
    private fun geocodePlaceAndDisplay(placePrediction: AutocompletePrediction) {
        // Construct the request URL
        val apiKey = BuildConfig.PLACES_API_KEY
        val requestURL =
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?place_id=${placePrediction.placeId}&key=$apiKey"

        // Use the HTTP request URL for Geocoding API to get geographic coordinates for the place
        val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestURL, null, { response ->
            try {
                val status: String = response.getString("status")
                if (status != "OK") {
                    Log.e(TAG, "$status " + response.getString("error_message"))
                }

                // Inspect the value of "results" and make sure it's not empty
                val results: JSONArray = response.getJSONArray("results")
                if (results.length() == 0) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "No results from geocoding request.")
                    return@JsonObjectRequest
                }

                // Use Gson to convert the response JSON object to a POJO
                val result: GeocodingResult = gson.fromJson(results.getString(0), GeocodingResult::class.java)
                displayDialog(placePrediction, result)
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }, { error ->
            Log.e(TAG, "Request failed", error)
        })

        // Add the request to the Request queue.
        queue.add(request)
    }

    private fun displayDialog(place: AutocompletePrediction, result: GeocodingResult) {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(place.getPrimaryText(null))
            .setMessage("Geocoding result:\n" + result.geometry?.location)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
            .show()
    }

    /**
     * Performs a Place Details request and displays the result in a dialog.
     *
     * @see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/place-details#maps_places_get_place_by_id-kotlin
     */
    private fun fetchPlaceAndDisplay(placePrediction: AutocompletePrediction) {
        // Specify the fields to return.
        val placeFields = listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS)

        // Construct a request object, passing the place ID and fields array.
        val request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placePrediction.placeId, placeFields)

        placesClient.fetchPlace(request)
            .addOnSuccessListener { response: FetchPlaceResponse ->
                val place = response.place
                AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(place.name)
                    .setMessage("located at:\n" + place.address)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                    .show()
                Log.i(TAG, "Place found: ${place.name}")
            }.addOnFailureListener { exception: Exception ->
                if (exception is ApiException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: ${exception.message} ${exception.statusCode}")
                }
            }
    }


    companion object {
        private val TAG = ProgrammaticAutocompleteGeocodingActivity::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

[Sample Project](https://github.com/googlemaps-samples/android-places-demos/tree/main)

You need to set the `.setTypesFilter(listOf(PlaceTypes.ESTABLISHMENT))` value.